# How to set up constructor and methods with ArrayList?

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I'm trying to learn about how constructors and methods work. I pretty much have the concepts down, it's just that I don't know how to set them up. I especially don't know how to use them with ArrayLists.

I'm trying to calculate and print the area of a rectangle, the commented parts are what I don't know how to set up.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class RectangleStats
{
// Private instance variables
// length is an ArrayList which will contain integer values, width is an array which will contain integer
// values, and area is an array which will contain decimal values.

//code goes here for instance variables goes here


// The constructor for the RectangleStats class takes an ArrayList and an array as parameters for
// length and width, respectively.

// code for constructor goes here

// The calcRectangleArea() method calculates the area of rectangles using the length and
// the width assigned to the private instance variables and assigns the results to the area array of type
// double. This method does not return anything.

// code for the calcRectangleArea() method goes here

// The printArea() method prints the values assigned to the area array using the most appropriate
// type of loop. This method does not return anything.

// code for the printArea() method goes here
}

// The RectangleStatsTesterClass assigns the length of two rectangles to an ArrayList and assigns the
// width of two rectangles to an array. The calcRectangleArea() and printArea() methods are invoked to
// calculate and print the area of the two rectangles.
public class RectangleStatsTesterClass2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
ArrayList intLength = new ArrayList();
intLength.add(7);
intLength.add(5);
int [ ] intWidth = {3, 4};

RectangleStats rectStats = new RectangleStats(intLength, intWidth);
rectStats.calcRectanglePerimeter();
rectStats.printArea();
}
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  Please see this post to give you a good idea of how to work with object oriented programming concepts.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676160/basics-to-creating-a-class-in-java/26677243#26677243

Comment: This is, once again, awful design. Why would you use a List for widths, and an array for lengths? Why not be consistent? Also, instead of storing widths and lengths seperately, why not define a class Rectangle, having a width and a length, defining a perimeter() and an area() methods, and simply pass a collection of Rectangle objects to the above class. All it would have to do would be to loop over the rectangles and sum their areas/perimeters. That would be proper OO design. Really, your teacher is awful at OO design.

Comment: Lol, I'll probably retake the course next semester on a MOOC or something. Is there somewhere I can see the more proper OO designs?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jnizet/a645b7efae4488ad8125

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class RectangleStats
{

    private List<Integer> length;

    private int[ ] width;

    double areas[];

    RectangleStats(List<Integer> length, int[] width){
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.areas = new double[this.width.length];
    }

    private void calcRectangleArea(){
        for(int i=0; i<width.length; i++){
            areas[i] = length.get(i) * width[i];
        }
    }

    public void printArea(){
        calcRectangleArea();
        for(int i=0; i<areas.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Area " + i + " : " + areas[i]);
        }
    }

    public void calcRectanglePerimeter(){
        for(int i=0; i<width.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Parameter for "+ i +"th Rectangle : " + (2 * (length.get(i) + width[i])));
        }
    }
}

public class RectangleStatsTesterClass2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> intLength = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        intLength.add(7);
        intLength.add(5);
        int [ ] intWidth = {3, 4};

        RectangleStats rectStats = new RectangleStats(intLength, intWidth);
        rectStats.calcRectanglePerimeter();
        rectStats.printArea();
    }
}
```